# Making site multi language support using google translate for React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-translate

For simple html projects i can simple refer this link.

> https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_google_translate.asp

But I'm trying to implement in react app . So I'm not able to replicate the code in react app.

```
componentDidMount() {
  googleTranslateElementInit(() => {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en'}, 'google_translate_element');
    });
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit";
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

And return render element .

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="google_translate_element"></div>
    );
  }
```

This is showing me error saying google , googleTranslateElementInit is not defined.

How can I use google translator in react app  ?
Also is there any npm packages which can translate whole site ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Move your google translate script to the root `index.html` of your project.

However, you should leave the below code at your desired location:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div id="google_translate_element"></div>
    );
  }
```

Fixes the problem easily.

Comment: this answer made my day :)

Comment: This didn't work for me. Any solutions for 2021?

Answer (score 1):

Late 2023 answer.
If you want to use Google Translate on the fly in React, using the TranslateElement. It does matter where or when you add it to the project as long as you append the script and the element that Google needs.
I made it with a custom hook:

```
function useGoogleTranslateScript() {
    useEffect(() => {
        const addScript = document.createElement('script');
        addScript.setAttribute(
            'src',
            '//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit'
        );
        document.body.appendChild(addScript);
        // debugger
        window.googleTranslateElementInit = () => {
            new window.google.translate.TranslateElement(
                {
                    pageLanguage: 'en',
                    includedLanguages: 'en,es',//here include all languages that you need
                },
                'google_translate_element'
            );
        };
    }, []);
}
```

You can place the hook where the translate component is gonna be. DONE
MORE ADVANCE: You can hide all Google components, and handle the dropdown by yourself, make sure you change the cookie of googtrans to the chosen language in the dropdown:
to set the cookies:

```
export const setCookie = (cName, cValue, exDays) => {
    let d = new Date(),
        expires = exDays;
    if (typeof exDays === 'number') {
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exDays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
    }
    document.cookie = cName + "=" + cValue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
```

to use it:

```
setCookie('googtrans', `/en/${value}`, 'Session')
//important
window.location.reload()
```

Don't forget to reload the location.

Answer (score 0):

Change render to:

```
render() {
  return (
    <script type='text/javascript' src='//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit' />
    <div id="google_translate_element"></div>
  );
}
```

Create googleTranslateElementInit and use window.google instead of google:

```
googleTranslateElementInit () {
  /* eslint-disable no-new */
  new window.google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'pt', layout: window.google.translate.TranslateElement.FloatPosition.TOP_LEFT}, 'google_translate_element')
}
```

Change componentDidMount to:

```
componentDidMount () {
  window.googleTranslateElementInit = this.googleTranslateElementInit
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those in 2021 and hopefully a few more years before Google decides to change implementation method, this is how I resolved it.

Add the below script to your `index.html` file found in the `public` directory:

```
<script src="https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit" async></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement(
      {
        pageLanguage: "en",
        layout: window.google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.VERTICAL,
      }, 
      'google_translate_element'
    );
  }
</script>
```

Then, create a component, to be imported anywhere you want to use the translate plugin, with any name of your choice. I will use `GoogleTranslate.jsx` for this purpose of this answer.

In the newly created component, paste this code:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

const GoogleTranslate = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // in some cases, the google translate script adds a style to the opening html tag.
    // this added style disables scrolling.
    // the next 3 lines removes this added style in order to re-enable scrolling.
    if (window.document.scrollingElement.hasAttribute("style")) {
      window.document.scrollingElement.setAttribute("style", "");
    }
  });

  return (
    <div id="google_translate_element"></div>
  );
};

export default GoogleTranslate;
```

Import the component wherever you want to use the translate plugin.

If this solution worked for you, kindly up vote so it can easily be shown to others searching. If it didn't, don't hesitate to drop a comment

Comment: Okay, so I copied this exactly and then imported the component in my navbar but it isn't loading the google ui. I see the script in source and network tabs, and even a div is added but there isn't any google translate ui added.

Comment: I noticed too that sometimes the Googe Translate UI doesn't show.
If you have Adblocker enabled, sometimes, it interferes. You can do the following:
1. Reload the page to see if it appears, or
2. Disable Adblocker and reload

Answer (score -1):

Go to public folder > index.html

add code in body tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

create component

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';

const GoogleTranslate = (props) => {

    return(
        <div id="google_translate_element"></div>
    )
}

export default GoogleTranslate
```

import GoogleTranslate from './GoogleTranslate';

```
<GoogleTranslate />
```